# Android Instrumentation Context/Permission Issues with Selendroid

Tags: android, testing, permissions, selendroid

specific question for you. I'm trying to write a feature in a test framework that adds call logs to the device/emulator. This requires android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOGS.

I am using selendroid, and have added this permission to the AndroidManifest. However, this permission is not in my application under test.

In the Instrumentation class, I inevitably try to run

```
getContext().getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

and it returns an error citing permission issues. getContext() is supposed to return the context of the instrumentation, which I assume is the selendroid app installed on the device, which should have the proper WRITE_CALL_LOGS permission.

Where am I going wrong?